# Nested dictionary to strings with numbering

Tags: python

I'd like to create strings with numbering ("1. Comment 1", "2. Comment 2",...) from a nested dictionary with comments (See an example of the nested dictionary in the code below). It should be printed only from dictionaries with "action": "COMMENTED".

This is what I've done so far. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601626/providing-an-id-for-each-recursed-item-in-nested-dictionary-of-lists-of-dictiona/12605652#12605652) helped me in parts of it:

It seems to be working, but is there a better way to achieve it?

```
activities = {
    "values": [
        {
            "action": "COMMENTED",
            "comment": {
                "text": "Comment 1",
                "comments": [
                    {
                        "text": "Reply 1",
                        "comments": []
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Reply 2",
                        "comments": [
                            {
                                "text": "Reply 2.1",
                                "comments": [
                                    {
                                        "text": "Reply 2.1.1",
                                        "comments": []
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Reply 3",
                        "comments": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "action": "COMMENTED",
            "comment": {
                "text": "Comment 2",
                "comments": []
            }
        },
        {
            "action": "COMMENTED",
            "comment": {
                "text": "Comment 3",
                "comments": []
            }
        }
    ]
}


def _loop_over_nested_comments(comment_dict, comment_index="1", reply_index=None):
    if not comment_dict:
        return

    if reply_index is None:
        number = f'{comment_index}'
    else:
        number = '{0}.{1}'.format(comment_index, reply_index)

    comment_text = comment_dict.get("text", "").strip()

    print(f"{number}. {comment_text}")

    for i, comment in enumerate(comment_dict.get("comments", []), start=1):
        _loop_over_nested_comments(comment, number, i)


comment_index = 1

for activity in activities["values"]:
    if activity["action"] == "COMMENTED":
        comment_dict = activity["comment"]
        _loop_over_nested_comments(comment_dict, str(comment_index))
        comment_index += 1
```

Desired output:

```
1. Comment 1
1.1. Reply 1
1.2. Reply 2
1.2.1. Reply 2.1
1.2.1.1. Reply 2.1.1
1.3. Reply 3
2. Comment 2
3. Comment 3
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I wrote what I've tried to far in the code block.

Comment: Ah lol I thought the first code block was just the dictionary structure, my bad

Comment: Can you post the current output as well?

Comment: It's the same as the desired output. I was just wondering if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: "better" in what way?

Comment: @HåkenLid, simpler, more readable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's what you're looking for nor if it's the best way to implement it but it works:

```
def format_comments(nested_comments, prefix):
  for i, comment in enumerate(nested_comments):
    s_prefix = prefix + f'{i + 1}.'
    print(s_prefix, comment.get('comment', {}).get('text') or comment['text'])
    format_comments(comment.get('comment', {}).get('comments') or comment.get('comments', []), s_prefix)
```

And then you use it like this:

```
format_comments(list(filter(lambda x: x['action'] == 'COMMENTED', activities['values'])), "")
```

Result:

```
1. Comment 1
1.1. Reply 1
1.2. Reply 2
1.2.1. Reply 2.1
1.2.1.1. Reply 2.1.1
1.3. Reply 3
2. Comment 2
3. Comment 3
```

Comment: Looks better, but forgot to write that only comments with "action": "COMMENTED" should be printed. I've added it to the question (The condition also appears in my code example).

Comment: @user2653179 I edited my answer, it only prints comments with "COMMENTED" as action now.